# Change Flutter hot reload time in VS Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

As soon as I start editing code, vs code starts hot reload, within a second. Its not wanted, because it starts hot reload before finishing the edit. So I want to change the delay time for hot reload in **VS code**. Is it possible anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in settings.json file:

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSaveTimeout": 1000,
"dart.flutterHotReloadOnSave": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official flutter documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_save-auto-save), by default the hot reload should only happen when you actually save the file (Ctrl + S) or the hot reload button, not automatically.

Unless you are using some Flutter specific way to automatically save - one way to solve your problem would be to set the [autoSaveDelay](http://%20Files:%20Auto%20Save%20Delay%20%20%20%20%20Controls%20the%20delay%20in%20ms%20after%20which%20a%20dirty%20editor%20is%20saved%20automatically.%20Only%20applies%20when%20Files:%20Auto%20Save%20is%20set%20to%20afterDelay.) the way you want it:

```
 Files: Auto Save Delay
 Controls the delay in ms after which a dirty editor is saved automatically.
 Only applies when Files: Auto Save is set to afterDelay.
 1000
```

By default this is set to 1000.